# What does "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method '...' on a null object reference" mean, and how do I solve it?

Tags: java, android, debugging, nullpointerexception

I'm getting the `NullPointerException` described in the title, but I don't understand how to use the information in the error message to debug it.  How do I know what's null, and what are common causes of that?

---

If you're seeing an error like `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method '...' on a null object reference`, this question aims to help solve your problem.

This also applies to all the following similar errors:

- `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method '...' on a null object reference`
- `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field '...' on a null object reference`
- `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from null array`
- `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array`

---

*Note: this is intended as a canonical self-answered question to provide a single place to point the many users who have questions about `NullPointerException`s on Android that contains Android-specific advice.*




*For the non-Android Java version of this question, or for more information, see [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/218384/208273)*

Comment: @MarquisofLorne May I try to convince you that this is a different question? The duplicate you've suggested, which I link in both my question and answer, does a good job of explaining the general principles of `NullPointerException`s. However, it does not explain how to use the Android-specific error message to determine which variable, exactly, is `null`. I've explained this by hand in comments _many_ times to people who complain that that canonical didn't help them, and wrote this question/answer to explain how to do that so that people won't have to explain it on dozens of individual posts.

Comment: I think my answer also explains where that question fits into this: it is the first step, and the rest of my answer builds on what's in that question and its answers by adding details of how the Android error message can be used.  Additionally, it explains common Android-specific causes: none of these are included in that canonical.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### What *is* a NullPointerException?

First off, if you don't understand what `null` is, or what a `NullPointerException` means, take a look at [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/218384/208273).  The rest of this answer will assume you've read that post.

### How to investigate the cause

Now that you know the basics, you need to figure out what line your error is on.  Take a look at [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3988794/208273) for information on how to do that.

Once you know what line the error is on, the next thing you need to do is figure out what variable, exactly, is null.  The error message will help you with that.

If your error looks like (the first `...` may be either `virtual` or `interface`—it's not important which):

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke ... method 'ReturnTypeOfMethod package.name.SomeClass.someMethod(...)' on a null object reference
```

That means that the variable of type `package.name.SomeClass` on which you tried to call `someMethod` was `null`.  It will also list the parameter types of the method, if any, where the `(...)` is in the example.

So, if you have this code:

```java
MyClass myVariable = new MyClass();
String logMessage = "some other text: " + myVariable.toString() + someOtherVariable.method();
```

and you get this error message:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.mypackagename.MyClass.toString()' on a null object reference
```

You know that `myVariable` is null, because that's the only variable of type `MyClass` that had `toString()` called on it.  The `java.lang.String` just means that `toString()` returns a `String`.

If the error is `Attempt to read from field...`, then apply the above advice, but looking for reading a field reference (`MyClass.someProperty`) rather than calling a method (`MyClass.someMethod()`).

If the error is `Attempt to read from null array`, look for anything on that line that reads from an array by index (for example, `someArrayVariable[i]`).

If the error is `Attempt to get length of null array`, look for a `.length` call on an array variable.

### Common root causes and fixes

#### findViewById before setting up View in Activity/Fragment

One common problem is calling findViewById before the View is actually set up.  For example, calling it in a member variable declaration:

```java
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private Button submitButton = findViewById(R.id.submitButton);
    // ... rest of Activity code ...
}
```

or before setContentView:

```java
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private Button submitButton;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        submitButton = findViewById(R.id.submitButton);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    // ... rest of Activity code ...
}
```

This doesn't work, because the `findViewById` is executed before you call `setContentView` in your `onCreate` method (for an `Activity`) or onCreateView (for a `Fragment`).  To fix this, make sure you call it after `setContentView`.  For `Fragment`s, you can either put the code in `onViewCreated`, or ensure that you are calling it on the `View` returned from the `LayoutInflater.inflate` call.

#### Incorrect layout ID/view ID/view not in layout

The problem is sometimes that there is no view with the ID passed to findViewById in the given layout.  Double check to make sure that your `setContentView` or `LayoutInflater.inflate` calls have the right layout ID (matches the XML filename) and that there is a View with that ID in that layout XML file (or one that it `<include>`s).