# How to implement TabLayout with ViewPager2 with recyclerView in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager, tablayout

I am stuck with this problem and I am not getting any solution to that,
I want a tablayout with viewpager2 which has recycler view inside it.
MainActivity.kt:-

```
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)
    pager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager)
    tab = findViewById(R.id.extra)

    val adapter = SectionsPagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager, lifecycle)
    pager.adapter = adapter
    TabLayoutMediator(tab,pager){tab,position ->
    when(position){
        0->{
            tab.text="RECENT"
        }
        1->{
            tab.text="SAVED"
        }
        2->{
            tab.text="TOOLS"
        }
    }
    }.attach()
```

SectionPagerAdapter.kt:-

```
  class SectionsPagerAdapter(fragmentManager: FragmentManager, lifecycle: Lifecycle):
    FragmentStateAdapter(fragmentManager, lifecycle) {
override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return 3    }

      override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
          // return a particular fragment page

          return when (position) {
              0 -> {
                  return tabrecentFragment()
              }
              1 -> {
                  return tabsavedFragment()
              }
              2 -> {
                  return tabtoolsFragment()
              }

              else -> {
                  return tabrecentFragment()
              }
          }
      }     
    }
```

I am getting error-:
Installation failed due to: ''package install-create -r -t --user current --full --dont-kill -S 7376065' returns error 'Unknown failure: cmd: Can't find service: package''
Retry
Failed to launch an application on all devices.

And when I connect my android device to run the app then it gives the error:-

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: findViewById(R.id.extra) must not be null
at com.whatsappstatussaverlatest.MainActivitySSW.onCreate(MainActivitySSW.kt:125)

If you have any solution then please help

Comment: What problem are you encountering doing that?  What's wrong with the code in this question?

Comment: @RyanM I am unable to run the application it is giving me the error which I have mentioned in the post above

Comment: You don't have a view with ID `extra` in your layout.  You need to fix that.  Take a look at the last section of my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62867558/208273